# Facing Syntax error in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
    $query = "UPDATE `$database`.`$member` SET `email` = \'$rowmem['email']\' WHERE `id` = $rowmem['mem_id']";
```

I don't know why but this line is showing an error in my page.

It's said there is an syntax error.

Can anyone correct it ??

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with parameter values.  That is dangerous and can lead to hard-to-debug syntax errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $query = "UPDATE `$database`.`$member` 
              SET `email` = '".$rowmem['email']."' 
              WHERE `id` = ".$rowmem['mem_id'];
```

I am sure it will be correct one.

Basically you added slashes `\` which are not needed but you need to do concatenation.